# Did apple change default font size on uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uifont

I have a strange problem where the font size in uitableviewcell (value 1 style..) is to big on my clients iphone. but not on any of my test devices. My client has 3.0.1

Did apple change the default size or is something else causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly answer your actual question, but I can provide an answer that I hope might still be useful:

Consider advising your client that they should not run iOS 3.0.1 these days in any situation where they use safari to access the internet, or where they are otherwise viewing pdf files (eg. mail attachments). There is at least one serious, remotely exploitable, security problem that could easily result in a hacker gaining access to any private data stored on your client's device and/or the ability to completely wipe the device and render it unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if Apple actually changed the default font size or if there was a bug on my clients iPhone, but the solution for me was to set the font size for every cell..